# Можно ли сделать так, что бы одна функция, запускаемая каждые 10 секунд с помощью библиотеки schedule, работала параллельно с другой функцией

Tags: python, telebot, schedule

Написал телеграм бота который сортирует сообщения и через определенное время должен их удалять, но по истечению времени, через которое schedule запускает функцию, которая удаляет сообщения, основная функция, которая их обрабатывает перестает работать, можно ли сделать что бы они работали параллельно или можно как-то по другому это реализовать

```
import datetime
import telebot
import sqlite3
import schedule
import time
import threading



token=''
bot=telebot.TeleBot(token,parse_mode='MARKDOWN')
timeformat="%Y-%m-%d"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now=f'{now:{timeformat}}'
db= sqlite3.connect('server.db',check_same_thread=False)
sql = db.cursor()
sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
   messageid BIGINT,
   date TEXT,
   message TEXT);
""")
db.commit()


def job():
    sql.execute("SELECT messageid FROM users")
    for row in sql.fetchall():
        print(row[0])
        bot.delete_message(chat_id='-1001615667874', 
message_id=row[0])
        sql.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE message = '+'")
        db.commit()
def run_threaded(job):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job())
    job_thread.start()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def chatting(message):
    a=list(message.text)
    if a[0]=='+':
        sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO users 
VALUES('{message.message_id}','{now}','{a[0]}');")
        db.commit()
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded,job)



bot.polling()

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вот здесь не верно job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job()) должно быть так job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job)

Comment: schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded,job) здесь что вы творите? ваш run_threaded и так job запускает.